# Ensuring interface implementations have the correct subclass for method

Tags: c#, .net

I'm designing a database interface, and am writing a method to add a table to the database. Different databases may need different parameters to add tables, so to solve that, I've made an abstract class for database parameters. An example which uses GoogleSheets:

```
public abstract class DatabaseTableParameters 
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    
    public DatabaseTableParameters(string key) {
        Key = key;
    }
}

public class GoogleSheetParameters : DatabaseTableParameters
{
    public int RangeColumnStart { get; set; }
    public int RangeRowStart { get; set; }
    public int RangeColumnEnd { get; set; }
    public bool FirstRowIsHeaders { get; set; }

    public GoogleSheetParameters(string key, int columnStart, int rowStart, int columnEnd, bool firstRowIsHeaders = false) : base(key)
    {
        RangeColumnStart = columnStart;
        RangeRowStart = rowStart;
        RangeColumnEnd = columnEnd;
        FirstRowIsHeaders = firstRowIsHeaders;
    }
}
```

The interface then has a method for adding a table to the database.

```
interface IDatabase<T>
{
    void AddTable(DatabaseTableParameters param);

}
```

The problem is that implementations of the database need to be restricted to a certain subclass of DatabaseTableParameters. I could use reflection to ensure that the passed parameter is the correct type, but that seems a little fragile to me.

Is there a better was of ensuring the correct parameter type is passed in?

Comment: Create a base interface for these types and use it with `where` constraint in your method.

Comment: if the parameter needs to be a GoogleSheetParameters   make it a  GoogleSheetParameters parameter, not an DatabaseTableParameters.   you will have to use something like pattern matching at some point to determine if the DatabaseTableParameters  is a GoogleSheetParameters however.

Comment: @aybe Could you be more specific? Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: What is the meaning of `T` in `IDatabase<T>`? Is that somehow related to the parameters?

Comment: @jspavs check my answer for an example

Comment: @JohnWu `T` refers to the table type (i.e GoogleSheetTable, etc). On second consideration that probably should be constrained somehow as well...

Comment: So how does your code know that a particular `T` goes with a particular type of table parameters?

Comment: @JohnWu That's the issue I'm trying to solve, to constrain a particular `T` to a subclass of DatabaseTableParameter

Answer (score 1):

Define your table parameters with a constraint that identifies what table type it goes with.

```
public abstract class DatabaseTableParameters<T> 
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public DatabaseTableParameters(string key) {
        Key = key;
    }
}

public class GoogleSheetParameters : DatabaseTableParameters<GoogleTable>
{
    //Etc...
```

Then define your database using this constraint:

```
interface IDatabase<T>
{
    void AddTable<T>(DatabaseTableParameters<T> param);
}


class GoogleSheetDatabase : IDatabase<GoogleTable>
{
    //etc....
```

This will force the `Add` method to require the appropriate type of parameters at compile time.

Comment: What's fundamentally wrong with your answer is that you tie a database with a particular table. Thankfully in real world a datatable can accept any table, not only specific ones.

Comment: @aybe Per the OP's comments, the implementation of `IDatabase` is table-specific. If that were not the case then OP's question wouldn't really make a lot of sense. I agree the design is strange and the term "database" here is different from common usage.

Comment: Ok, makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, you can add `Table1` but not `Table2` thanks to `where`

```
public interface ITable
{
    string Key { get; set; }
}

public abstract class TableBase : ITable
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public interface ITableExt
{
    int A { get; set; }

    string Key { get; set; }
}

public class Table1 : TableBase, ITableExt
{
    public int A { get; set; }
}

public class Table2 : TableBase
{
    public int A { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        Add(new Table1());
        // Add(new Table2()); // not possible
    }
    public void Add<T>(T value) where T : TableBase, ITableExt
    {

    }
}
```